# Thread containing a JVM does not kill the JVM when the thread dies

Tags: c#, multithreading, jvm

I've wrote a small program in C# that will be integrated into cruise control (EDIT: oops, pressed enter too early) that creates certain (and not-predefined) JVM's in their own separate threads. However, when killing the thread the JVM still exists and is not unloaded. This functionality works correctly with .bat files- but if they call a JVM it still remains open still!

Each thread is created from an instance of this class and calls Run()

_Critical is used by the main process for testing reasons.

```
class BatThread
{
    private string _args, _fileName;
    private bool _critical;
    public ManualResetEvent Flag;

    public BatThread(string fileName, string args, bool critical)
    {
        _fileName = fileName;
        _args = args;
        _critical = critical;
        Flag = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    }
    public void Run()
    {
        using (Process Proc = new Process())
        {
            Proc.StartInfo.FileName = _fileName;
            Proc.StartInfo.Arguments = _args;
            Proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = false;
            Proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = false;
            Proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
            Proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
            Proc.Start();

            while (true)
            {
                if (Proc.WaitForExit(100))
                {
                    break;
                }
                else if (this.Flag.WaitOne(100))
                {
                    Proc.Kill();
                    break;
                }
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
            }
            this.Flag.Set();
        }
    }

    public bool critical { get { return _critical; } }

}
```

Comment: Closed why? The question was about why processes remain after a thread that creates them closes .. and how to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work, because killing the thread does not automatically kills the process (independent) that you spawned.
In general, killing a thread is bad practice. You should signal the thread to exit, so it can do cleanup (tear the process down), and return cleanly.

Comment: Yes. I usually signal the thread to exit, but the Proc.Kill() does not seem to be WAI, and even when I Abort() the thread in the main process for not exiting fast enough, the JVM still remains.

Comment: So your problem is that you call Abort on the new process main thread and the JVM does not exit? Or that Proc.Kill does not seem to kill the process?

Comment: The flag is set in the main process before the thread is aborted (after a short time), so both. -- The main process does detect when one of two process are complete and exits and tries to kill the other one but fails

Comment: So it is Proc.Kill that "does not work"? How does it fails, does it return any error?
Also, the process you spawn is "java.exe" or something else?

Comment: Solved it: the thread was stuck in Sleep() for too long so it never got a chance to call Proc.Kill() - hence the JVM remained. I fixed it by reducing the sleep time in the thread itsself .. very odd that .bat's worked correctly - maybe I just got lucky..

Comment: Yes, it still seems you have some timing issues there... For example, I do not understand why you do so many different sleeps (on the proc handle, on an event handle, on the thread itself...

Comment: Well.. assume the JVMs I am running are unreliable and are being tested against (and that I might have several console-based applications running from this in order to test the JVM)- and as the entire testing process is automated I need to have a way to know if the process is still running and have a way to signal to stop processes because something screwed up. Don't want millions of useless processes running remotely on a testing box that's been left to be automated.